# How to remove this lines from input group add on, bootstrap

Tags: html, css

[image]

How to remove the lines around the icon like place the icon inside the searchbox I tried background transparent border 0 still not working the border are still there

here's what I did

```
                <center>
      <div class="input-group col-xs-4 col-md-6" >
         <input type="text" name="search" id="search-building" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..." required>
         <div class="input-group-addon">
      <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
    </div>
    </div> 
   </center>
```

CSS

```
.input-group-addon{ 
    border:0;
    background:white;
     pointer-events: none;

  }
```

[image]

Comment: which border you want to remove?

Comment: right side the one with the icon I want the icon like to be putted inside the search box @AbasahebGaware

Comment: you can try this `.input-group{ border-right : 0 !important; } .input-group input{ border-right : 0 !important; }` @Doe

Comment: I've added new pic how do I remove the grey part @AbasahebGaware

Comment: add just `.input-group-addon{  background:white; }` @Doe

Answer (score 0):

Your css class rules aren't being applied because of the specificity... to solve it add a parent to your selector..

```css
.input-group .input-group-addon{ 
    border:0;
    background:white;
     pointer-events: none;

  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="input-group col-xs-4 col-md-6" >
         <input type="text" name="search" id="search-building" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..." required>
         <div class="input-group-addon">
      <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
    </div>
```

Comment: well you can open your devtools and see which class is overwriting your rules, if you can't find it you can add !important at the end of each property, it should work with that but (is a bad practice..)

Answer (score 0):

Check this out.

UPDATED:
Changed as per the discussion below.

```css
.input-group input {
      border-right: none;
}

.input-group .input-group-addon {
  background: inherit;
}

div {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div>
<center>
      <div class="input-group col-xs-4 col-md-6" >
         <input type="text" name="search" id="search-building" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..." required>
         <div class="input-group-addon">
      <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
    </div>
    </div> 
   </center></div>
```

Comment: I dont have a white background @ivp any idea how to?

Comment: 'background: white' instead of 'background: inherit'.
  Hope it help @Doe. Let me know if it doesn't

Comment: I have an image background @ivp

Comment: Do you want complete input box along with the search icon with image as background? I thought, you have input box like above (in white), and just want to change the search icon appearance

Comment: Ive added some new pic how do I remove the grey part? @ivp

Comment: Updated the answer as per your question. Check this. Hope it help. The point is, background: inherit should be enough. If not, try background: initial.